# Firebase mail link sign-in (Dynamic Links) is not working on device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using mail link sign-in in my application. When I test with a simulator, mail link sign-in is completely working. But when I test with a device, it does not work.

Clicking sign-in link on iPhone opens Safari like this.

[image: sign-in link web page]

But tapping OPEN button doesn't open my app.
Further, it opens my deep link url in spite of setting to open AppStore if user doesn't install my app in Firebase Console.

My code is working in a simulator. So, is there anything that I have to need setting for testing sign-in link or Dynamic Links in device?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I did the following:

- Delete the app
- Clean the project
- Restart a device

Answer (score 0):

[image]
No need to wipe the app. Long press on the link and select your app as the destination.